# Alternative for synchronized block in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I use following code for guarantee `startTime` variable set once only:

```
public class Processor
{
    private Date startTime;

    public void doProcess()
    {
        if(startTime == null)
            synchronized(this)
            {
                  if(startTime == null)
                  {
                     startTime = new Date();
                  }
            }

        // do somethings
    }
}
```

I will guarantee by this code for  variable instantiated once only for any number of invoking `process` method call.

My question is:

Is there alternative approach for my code be more concise? (for sample remove `if` & `synchronized` statements)

Comment: I think you can use atomic reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on you comments, you could use AtomicReference

```
firstStartTime.compareAndSet(null, new Date());
```

or AtomicLong

```
firstStartTime.compareAndSet(0L, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

---

I would use

```
private final Date startTime = new Date();
```

or

```
private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: The idea seems to be to trigger the startTime when `doProcess` is called... So I suppose you are suggesting to start the timer when a `Processor` object is created.

Comment: But in this case startTime will contains timestamp when class was loaded, not when method was called first time?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Thanks, but your approach has `final` keyword and must initialized in definition time or in constructor, my sample is not in constructor.

Comment: @MJM This is true. How many milli-seconds delay do you expect between the object being created and doProcess called for the first time?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Object created in start up  time of application but `doProcess` called when a transaction incoming to application(when end-user do a specified action)

Comment: So its the first time a user triggers the process. If its triggered again, you don't want it to change?

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, I want this variable initialized in first user triggered the process.

Comment: So its really the `firstStartTime` I would have considered the `startTime` to be the start of the last run.

Comment: +1 This is the perfect fit for OP's requirement. Proper semantics, no object waste, full speed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "This is the perfect fit for OP's requirement" really but you say "no object waste", this is wrong, in specified status a `Date`  instance waste, when tow threads first time go to after `if`  statement ;)

Comment: MJM, you won't get any better without locking. If there was something **very, very** heavy involved, say a **million** times heavier than a `Date`, you'd realistically need something more. In that case you should read about the proper way to implement the double-check idiom, for example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/bloch_effective_08_qa.html). It's straight from Josh Bloch's mouth. For your requirement that idiom is **not** a perfect fit for being an overkill by many orders of magnitude. In fact, with 100 calls per minute, even this is overkill.

Comment: Date takes about 200 ns. If you have multiple threads trying to update `firstStartTime` in the same 200 ns, you will get a wasted object producing about 16-24 bytes of garbage. Given this is very rare and very little impact, you may prefer the make the solution as simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have another question: Is your answer and `Alex D` answer same result?

Comment: @PeterLawrey curious, in your AtomicReference/Long suggestion, why would the first get() call be needed? Maybe there is a slight performance gain there, but may not be a meaningful optimization?

Comment: @sjlee It might be more efficient, but I don't know for sure it is.  One line is simpler so I have changed it.

Answer (score 12):

Use [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html):

```
public class Processor {
  private final AtomicReference<Date> startTime = new AtomicReference<Date>();
  public void doProcess() {
    if (this.startTime.compareAndSet(null, new Date())) {
      // do something first time only
    }
    // do somethings
  }
}
```

Comment: This wastes a `Date` instance for every call, it can be improved.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the OP's code. He wants to initialize `startTime` *only* the first time `doProcess()` is called.

Comment: @yegor256 I don't understand what is it work? I know `getAndSet` method return old value and then set new value to passed it.

Comment: @yegor256 I understand your suggestion,thanks but still it create a `Date`  object per invoking `doProcess` method.

Comment: instantiation of `Date` is a cheap operation, see how the class is implemented in JDK: it has very small memory footprint

Comment: @yegor256 You're right,  but we must trying write idea code. In my application maybe `doProcess` triggers 100 time in one minute so I have to find best approach.

Comment: you can change the if block to `if((startTime.get() == null) && startTime.compareAndSet(null, new Date()))`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is an example of so called "double check locking." Please read this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html). It explains why this trick does not work in java although it is very smart.

Comment: Brien Goetz is very smart, but that article is 11 years old.  The JVM has certainly changed a great deal since then.  I'd wonder if there was a more recent article that dealt with JVM 6 or newer.

Comment: @duffymo The semantics have not changed and this idiom is still a failure. The only relevant change was the fixed semantics of `volatile` that happened with Java 1.5. `volatile` is BTW exactly what OP needs to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

So from my understanding you need a singleton which is:

1. Short, easy to implement/understand.
2. Only initialized when `doProcess` is called.

I suggest the following implementation using a nested class:

```
public class Processor {
    private Date startTime;

    private static class Nested {
        public static final Date date = new Date();
    }

    public void doProcess() {
        startTime = Nested.date; // initialized on first reference
        // do somethings
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is nice but I want decrease my LOC(line of code) ;) I  up-vote to this.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up what other posters have already explained:

```
private volatile Date startTime;

public void doProcess()
{
   if(startTime == null) startTime = new Date();
   // ...
}
```

Concise enough for you?

Comment: @Alex I wrote your suggestion first but thinking over it and found it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: The only danger is that multiple threads could initialize `startTime` redundantly, which wouldn't cause anything bad to happen.

Comment: BTW, `java.lang.String` uses the same strategy for lazily initializing its cached hash value. If the above code is "not thread-safe", that means `java.lang.String` is also "not thread-safe".

Answer (score 0):

**1** What you have used is known as `double checked locking`.

**2.** There are another 2 ways to do it

```
  - Use synchronized on the Method
  - Initialize the static variable during declaration.
```

**3.** As you want an example with No `if` and `synchronized` keyword, i am showing you the `Initialize the static variable during declaration.` way.

```
public class MyClass{

  private static MyClass unique = new MyClass();

  private MyClass{}

  public static MyClass getInstance(){

      return unique;

  }

 }
```